# Extract Elastic Net penalized logistic regression Coefficients from mlr

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, logistic-regression, mlr

I have read a few other answers but none have worked for me in extracting the penalized logistic regression coefficients from my final trained model.

```
penlrntune = makeLearner("classif.glmnet", predict.type = "prob", par.vals = logres.mbo$x)
set.seed(9)
pen_model_tune <- mlr::train(penlrntune, task = trn.task)

## when i run coef(getLearnerModel(pen_model_tune)
coef(getLearnerModel(pen_model_tune, more.unwrap = TRUE))
36 x 83 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   [[ suppressing 45 column names ‘s0’, ‘s1’, ‘s2’ ... ]]
   [[ suppressing 45 column names ‘s0’, ‘s1’, ‘s2’ ... ]]
                                                                                                              
(Intercept)   -3.15367 -3.251889 -3.3528 -3.455813 -3.560283 -3.665525 -3.792622 -3.816052 -3.093964 -2.249888
Obesity        .        .         .       .         .         .         .         .         .         .       
Diabetes       .        .         .       .         .         .         .         .         .         .       
Smoke          .        .         .       .         .         .         .         .         .         .       
Pulm           .        .         .       .         .         .         .         .         .         .       
Cardiac        .        .         .       .         .         .         .         .         .         .       
Dyspnea        .        .         .       .         .         .         .         .         .         .       
Steroids       .        .         .       .         .         .         .         .         .         .       
RenalComorb    .        .         .       .         .         .         .         .         .         .       
emergency.Yes  .        .         .       .         .         .         .         .         .         .       
ASA3           .        .         .       .         .         .         .         .         .         .
```

this doesn't make much sense as you can tell. The model otherwise works well, so i must be missing something.

I have reproduced this issue using the pimaindiansdiabetes2 dataset from the mlbench package, when all i want is the logistic regression coefficients from the trained model.

```
library(mlbench)
library(mlr)
# Load the data and remove NAs
data("PimaIndiansDiabetes2", package = "mlbench")
PimaIndiansDiabetes2 <- na.omit(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)
PimaIndiansDiabetes2 <- PimaIndiansDiabetes2[2:9]
set.seed(9)
indian.task = makeClassifTask(data=PimaIndiansDiabetes2, target = "diabetes", positive = "pos")
testlrn <-makeLearner("classif.glmnet", predict.type = "prob", par.vals = list(alpha = 0.339, s=0.00556))
testlrn_train <- mlr::train(testlrn, indian.task)
coef(getLearnerModel(testlrn_train))

8 x 70 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   [[ suppressing 70 column names ‘s0’, ‘s1’, ‘s2’ ... ]]
                                                                                                   
(Intercept) -0.7008101 -0.832287755 -0.96789148 -1.107230550 -1.249880176 -1.395389472 -1.593724136
glucose      .          0.001070684  0.00217191  0.003300326  0.004452356  0.005624265  0.006706897
pressure     .          .            .           .            .            .            .          
triceps      .          .            .           .            .            .            .          
insulin      .          .            .           .            .            .            .          
mass         .          .            .           .            .            .            .          
pedigree     .          .            .           .            .            .            .          
age          .          .            .           .            .            .            0.002042163
                                                                                                         
(Intercept) -1.795136758 -1.995953151 -2.264942612 -2.5516299342 -2.840942953 -3.125132e+00 -3.411189e+00
glucose      0.007787101  0.008868089  0.009892814  0.0108901514  0.011863974  1.280009e-02  1.367427e-02
pressure     .            .            .            .             .            .             .           
triceps      .            .            .            0.0003408727  0.001478306  2.543441e-03  3.465742e-03
insulin      .            .            .            .             .            2.182663e-05  6.272459e-05
mass         .            .            0.002302462  0.0049824211  0.007195585  9.319553e-03  1.125890e-02
pedigree     .            .            .            .             .            4.557533e-03  4.506202e-02
age          0.004173928  0.006265506  0.008297616  0.0102624303  0.012130153  1.393673e-02  1.565741e-02
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, I have added an example that reproduced the issue.

Comment: Thanks -- what exactly are you looking for? I'm getting a lot more output than you posted with lots of non-zero coefficients. I don't see anything obviously wrong with it.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I am looking for the global feature importance coefficients—and yes I too get much more output but felt that it wasn’t necessary to post and clutter up the sheet with, sorry if that was the wrong move

Comment: `getLearnerModel()` gets you the fully fitted model, {mlr} just stores it and does not alter it in any way.

Comment: @pat-s interesting, so is there a way to extract the final coefficients for each variable from the model?

Comment: I don't know, this is a glmnet thing. I suggest to fit a toy model as shown in the examples without mlr and then try to achieve what you want. Afterwards, use mlr to simplify your workflow :)

Comment: @pat-s I see, I suppose I'll just fit a model using some other penalized logistic regression function using the hyperparams I tuned using mlr and just get the coefficients that way as a workaround with the same seed and the results should be good enough.

Comment: This sounds dangerous and I really would stick with one implementation. Or just dive more into glmnet. Coefficients are there.